# How to set time windows of google ortools for the next day?

Tags: or-tools

im trying the example on this guideline 
https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrptw

this is array of `timeWindows`

```java
public final long[][] timeWindows = {
        {0, 5}, // depot
        {7, 12}, // 1
        {10, 15}, // 2
        {16, 18}, // 3
        {10, 13}, // 4
        {0, 5}, // 5
        {5, 10}, // 6
        {0, 4}, // 7
        {5, 10}, // 8
        {0, 3}, // 9
        {10, 16}, // 10
        {10, 15}, // 11
        {0, 5}, // 12
        {5, 10}, // 13
        {7, 8}, // 14
        {10, 15}, // 15
        {11, 15}, // 16
    };
```

i have few questions about this

- how can i configure timewindows in two days, like from 23:00 today to 2:00 tomorrow? i tried {23,2} and solver has exception
- How can i set time window with minutes? like 20:20 - 21:00?
- What will be depart time here? is it the time of depot (first node)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solver does not know anything about time units (hours, minutes, seconds...)

Please look at the code to see where the time windows are translated into integer numbers to be passed to the solver.
Then you will be able to tweak the logic of the code, and the data to accommodate your need.

Comment: you're correct. i just use incremental number to present for time unit.